# Register same runner for multiple GitLab repos

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I have 1 GitLab repo with 1 "Specific Runner" which is working with GitLab Pages.

I want to create a 2nd GitLab repo and use the same "Specific Runner" from the other repo. Is that possible?

I have tired configuring the config.toml by changing the concurrent property to 2 and by adding another runner property with the corresponding url and token to the new repository.

Then ran 'gitlab-runner list' and it shows I have 2 runners. Then 'gitlab-runner start'. But then in GitLab CI/CD settings, the runner is not visible there.

Do I need to install another runner or can I just register another runner in config.toml?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. Yes you can install 1 runner and register others for different repositories.

Instead if manually editing the config.toml, you have to register new runners with gitlab-runners register command. That will fix it.

Comment: Could you share what your `config.toml` file looks like after registering one runner to multiple projects? Thanks!

Comment: two different fields [[runners]] are present

Answer (score 0):

You've to register gitlab runner 2 times with different token in the same.
You've to follow below steps:

1. Open Project A repo and go to ci/cd, copy token and register with gitlab runner.
2. Open Project B repo and go to ci/cd, copy token and register with gitlab runner.